# Using request to get API results, and integrating into Hubot response

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, requestjs

I have a Hubot plugin, that listens for JIRA webhooks, and announces in a room when new tickets are created:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.router.post '/hubot/tickets', (req, res) ->
    data = if req.body.payload? then JSON.parse req.body.payload else req.body
    if data.webhookEvent = 'jira:issue_created'
      console.dir("#{new Date()} New ticket created")
      shortened_summary = if data.issue.fields.summary.length >= 20 then data.issue.fields.summary.substring(0, 20) + ' ...' else data.issue.fields.summary
      shortened_description = if data.issue.fields.description.length >= 50 then data.issue.fields.description.substring(0, 50) + ' ...' else data.issue.fields.description
      console.log("New **#{data.issue.fields.priority.name.split ' ', 1}** created by #{data.user.name} (**#{data.issue.fields.customfield_10030.name}**) - #{shortened_summary} - #{shortened_description}")
      robot.messageRoom "glados-test", "New **#{data.issue.fields.priority.name.split ' ', 1}** | #{data.user.name} (**#{data.issue.fields.customfield_10030.name}**) | #{shortened_summary} | #{shortened_description}"
    res.send 'OK'
```

I'd like to extend this, to perform lookup against a remote API - basically, there's extra info I want to lookup, then add into the message I'm passing to `room.messageRoom`. I'm using request, because I need digest support.

So the following snippet works fine on its own.

```
request = require('request')

company_lookup = request.get('https://example.com/clients/api/project?name=FOOBAR', (error, response, body) ->
  contracts = JSON.parse(body)['contracts']
  console.log contracts
).auth('johnsmith', 'johnspassword', false)
```

And this is where my JS/Node newbness comes out...lol.

I can process the response inside the callback - but I'm really sure how to access it outside of that callback?

And how should I be integrating this into the webhook processing code - do I just move the snippet inside the if block, and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a middleware (supposing you are using Express with Node.js) so you can add the `company_lookup` response to the `req` and use it into any route where you add the middleware. http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

For example:

server.js

```
var middlewares = require('./middlewares');
module.exports = function (robot) {
    // Tell the route to execute the middleware before continue
    return robot.router.post(middlewares.company_loop, '/hubot/tickets', function (req, res) {
        // Now in the req you have also the middleware response attached to req.contracts
        console.log(req.contracts);
        return res.send('OK');
    });
};
```

middlewares.js

```
var request = require('request');
// This is your middleware where you can attach your response to the req
exports.company_lookup = function (req, res, next) {
    request.get('https://example.com/clients/api/project?name=FOOBAR', function (error, response, body) {
        var contracts;
        contracts = JSON.parse(body)['contracts'];
        // Add the response to req
        req.contracts = contracts;
        // Tell it to continue
        next();
    }).auth('johnsmith', 'johnspassword', false);
};
```